# How to end DB connection using Mysql2 Promise?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The following code works as expected, except that I can't seem to figure out how to call `con.end();`

db.js:

```
const
mysql = require('mysql2/promise'),
config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'webhooks'
};

module.exports = async () => {
  const
  con = await mysql.createConnection(config),
  sql = 'SELECT * FROM table',
  data = [];

  let [rows, fields] = await con.execute(sql);

  return rows;
}
```

app.js:

```
const test = require('./db.js');

test.then(console.log);
```

I've tried adding `con.end();` right before `return rows;`, and I've also tried various combinations of `test.then(...).catch(...).then(() => con.end());` but no results.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `async` **exports** function since all **async operations** (connection, fetch) are being awaited. The `con.end()` should ideally be an `async` operation and can be simply awaited as the results are fetched and resolved just before.

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const
  con = await mysql.createConnection(config),
  sql = 'SELECT * FROM table',
  data = [];

  let [rows, fields] = await con.execute(sql);
  await con.end();
  return rows;
}
```

An then in **app.js** get rows that were returned:

```
const test = require('./db.js');

test.then(rowsResults => console.log(rowsResults)); //only rows were returned
```

- `con` object can also be sent as part of `returned promise` along with `rows` and subsequently can be closed in thenable of test but that would seem more verbose in this case.